# Grids and input field, small screen

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a problem with the design on the small screen.
I have grid layout. Everything is working fine. But when I make the screen smaller, the input field doesn't want to shrink like other elements.
Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you!
[Problem Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR6Oa.png)

```
nav {
    
    background-color: #B0B5BD;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 7;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0.1rem;
}

.nav_buttons {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    gap: 1rem;
}

#btn_makeup {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

#btn_store {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

#btn_content {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

#btn_about {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
}

.search-box {
    grid-column: 5 / 6;
    padding-top: 0.3rem;
}
```

Comment: can you put the code you write, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

if you put `width: 100%` in your input It will work

```css
nav input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

so it will 100% of parent div, that is 1fr (1fr is responsive depending on device size, that it!)

also if you want to be if you want to get precise, you can use `calc(100% - var(--WidthOfSearchIconDiv));` which I have not used here (because it is not the main purpose of the question)

---

here is the code, I corrected also other things :)

for example I removed the `grid-columns` that were not needed because there was already `grid-template-columns`

**here the code**

```css
nav {
  background-color: #B0B5BD;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 0.1rem;
  place-items: center;
}

.nav_buttons {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.search-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

nav svg {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

#btn_search {
  margin: 0 0.3rem;
}

nav input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav_buttons">
    <div id="btn_makeup">MAKEUP</div>
    <div id="btn_store">STORE</div>
    <div id="btn_content">CONTENT</div>
    <div id="btn_about">ABOUT</div>
    <div class="search-box">
      <input type="search" placeholder="search">
      <!-- search icon -->
      <div id="btn_search"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="magnifying-glass" class="svg-inline--fa fa-magnifying-glass" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z"></path></svg></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```